# Is it correct to say that all nonstationary states in a superposition of nondegenerate eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, superposition

Stationary states no not evolve with time, whereas nonstationary states do the opposite.
I have essentially a two small questions (assume a time-independent Hamiltonian):

1. Is it true to say that a stationary state is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian operator, or a linear combination (superposition) of eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian with degenerate eigenenergy values?
2. Is it true to say that a nonstationary state is a linear combination (superposition) of eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian with nondegenerate eigenenergy values?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Yes, a stationary state "evolves" in time just with an overall (irrelevant) phase factor (trivial evolution, it is stationary!).
If a state $|\alpha\rangle$ is made with eigenstates $|n,k\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian $H$ that have all the same energy,
$$
|\alpha\rangle =\sum_k \alpha_k|n,k\rangle \qquad H|n,k\rangle=E_n|n,k\rangle \, \, \forall k \,\, \, \, \,  (\hbar=1),
$$
then the overall phase factor is the same for each term in the linear superposition:

$$
  e^{-i Ht}|s\rangle   =   \sum_k e^{-i E_nt} \alpha_k|n,k\rangle =
e^{-i E_nt}|s\rangle \propto |s\rangle
$$

2 - Yes, a non-stationary phase is any linear superposition of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with at least two different energy eigenvalues (you can easily see that the trick above does not work anymore as there are intrinsic phase differences between the states in the linear superposition).

Comment: Actually states do not evolve at all. They are defined up to phases, so $e^{itE}$ does not matter.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I agree, I used bad wording. Thank you for the clarification!